# Translating rewriting from htaccess to nginx

Tags: .htaccess, nginx

I have `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^thumb/(.*)x(.*)/r/(.*) thumb.php?w=$1&h=$2&src=$3
RewriteRule ^medias/(.*) files.php?file=$1

RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)(\.html|\.htm)$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)(\.rss|\.atom|\.txt)$ index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php [L]
```

Nginx rewriting is:

```
rewrite ^/thumb/(.*)x(.*)/r/(.*) /thumb.php?w=$1&h=$2&src=$3;
rewrite ^/medias/(.*) /files.php?file=$1;
rewrite ^/sitemap\.xml$ /index.php break;
rewrite ^/(.*)(\.html|\.htm)$ /index.php break;
rewrite ^/(.*)(\.rss|\.atom|\.txt)$ /index.php break;
```

When accessing categories, I get the home page.

Any help please

Thanks

Comment: What is the url when "accessing categories"?

Comment: Hi, it's : /CategoryName/index.1.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Nginx configuration is typically approached a bit differently, with lots of location blocks.

It's difficult for me to test this, but this might help you forward:

```
# Nginx excludes the query string (part after the ?) before trying to match
location = /index.php {
    # FastCGI PHP stuff here
}

location ~ ^/thumb/([^/]+)x([^/]+)/r/([^/]+) {
    rewrite ^ /thumb.php?w=$1&h=$2&src=$3 break;
}

location ~ ^/medias/(.*) {
    rewrite ^ /files.php?file=$1 break;

    # To be honest I would try to avoid serving files through PHP. It's much more efficient to let Nginx serve them directly with something like:
    root /path/to/media's/parent;
    try_files $uri =404;
}

location ~ ^/sitemap\.xml$ {
    rewrite ^ index.php break;
}

location ~ (\.html|\.htm|\.rss|\.atom|\.txt)$ {
    rewrite ^ index.php break;
}

# Catch-all
location / {
    try_files $uri index.php;
}
```

The fact that you have to test for extensions, with regexes, means they kind of all have to use regexes. That's because those blocks with regexes are evaluated before longest-prefix blocks. Make sure to read [Nginx' documentation about location blocks](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for a better explanation, with examples.